# Container with 'cab command handler ' like functionality

Tags: spring4d

I have started to use spring container and was wondering if there is any functionality available in spring4d similar to cab command handlers allowing control (visible / enable) of menu commands etc. How is everyone else dealing with this in a structured way?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain a bit more - I don't know that CAB does with command handlers that makes it any special.

Comment: Sorry if it was a bit vague. Using CAB in an application (host) that has menus each menuitem that has a commandhandler assigned will follow state of the commandhandler. For instance setting the commandhandler to disabled will also disable the menu item. I am essentially trying to understand what is the best way to manage (disable / enable / control visibility) a host application's menuitems in the context of using a spring4d container. The link might explain it a bit better, **https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/commands-in-the-cab-introduction-to-cabscsf-part-10/**

Comment: I think `TAction` does what you want and that has nothing to do with the Spring4D DI container.

Comment: I am aware of taction but that does not allow me to refer to handler by name across whole application scope without tightly coupling interface implementations together. If I have a registered interface managed by container that needs to disable a menuitem exposed by host what would be best way keeping it loosely coupled still?

Comment: I would let the host provide an `IMenuService` interface to do so.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, so I am not 're-inventing the wheel' by doing so as there is nothing I am missing in spring that already caters to this specifically.